# is there a page detailing incompatibilities between Julia versions

Tags: julia, compatibility, factorial, versions

Is there a page or document describing incompatibilities between Julia versions? 
Specifically, things like factorial() and lfact() seem to have silently disappeared between the 0.6 and 0.7 documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Julialang/julia/NEWS.md](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md) page is used to describe to developers the language changes between the versions.